# iOS6 - How to Scroll a UITableView with dynamic frame height inside UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uiscrollview

I'm using iOS6 and Xcode 4.5.2.
Using the storyboard I created the following diagram:

[image]

Here is what I'm currently doing in my code flow:

1) I declare the UITableView object in the .h file in this way:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablePOI;
```

2) Since I populate the UITableView with data coming from a web request,
I don't know in advance the UITableView Frame height. In the storyboard I initialize to 260f the UITableView Frame height.

3) I fetch web data within the viewDidLoad function, then I populate UITableView and set a new frame and contentSize for it. After this I set the contentSize for the UIScrollView component in this way:

```
[self.tablePOI setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 800)];
[self.tablePOI setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

Problem is UITableView is cut to the height previously initialized into the storyboard (260f), therefore UIScrollView does not scroll, but just bounce.

How can I get a scroll when using a UITableView component with dynamic height?

PS.
I've also thought to generate via code the UITableView component without using the storyboard, but with this approach I must declare UITableView as retain and then I have to manage memory allocation. I don't really want to go this way (dealloc has been deprecated).

Comment: why there os need of scrollview when tableview has its own scroll by default . can you please show your design ?

Comment: becaouse I want to scroll both collectionView and UITableView as shown in the attached picture